# Changing a Table Row's colour onload

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

So I'm working on a webpage where an admin can disable and enable users. I have it so when the admin disables or enables a user, the text in the user's table row will change colour accordingly. However, I can't seem to change the row's colour onload. So they all show up as the enabled colour (Black). Here's my code so far;

```
function loadRow(){


    var check_array = document.getElementsByName("checkbox[]");
    var array_size = check_array.length;

    for(var i =0; i < array_size; i++){
        if(check_array[i].checked){
            var rowId = check_array[i].value;
            document.getElementById(rowId).style.color = "#4D4A49"; 
        }
    }

}
```

My rows are all populated through a PHP connection to my database, and here's the code for that;

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $output .= '<tr id="row'. $row['id'] .'"><td>' . $row['name'] .'</td>
                <td>'. $row['username'] .'</td>
                <td>' . $row['email'] . '</td>
                <td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox'. $row['id'] .'"  value="' . $row['id'] . '" onchange="disableUser(this.value)" ' . ($row['disable'] == 0 ? 'checked' : '') .'/></td>
                <td><a href="deleteUser.php">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>';
}
```

The HTML then looks like this;

```
<table border="1">
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Username</th><th>Email</th><th>Disabled</th><th>Delete</th></tr>
    <?php echo $output; ?>
</table>
```

I am wondering if the onload is in the wrong place or not. Any suggestions? If I left something out, and am unclear, please let me know and I'll edit my post. Thanks.

Comment: if you need a ROW color probably you need a background color, so try `...  style.backgroundColor = '#4D4A49';` The 'color' is for the text color, and possibly you override it somewhere in styles

Comment: @Serg It's supposed to just change the text colour. I forgot to specify that. I just edited it.

Comment: Have you tried degugging inside the loop to check that check_array non-empty and the if statement is being passed?

Comment: @CJ. I added an alert just now in the for loop to make sure it's getting the check boxes and their ID's, and that works. As well as placing an alert inside the if statement. The loop and if statement appear to be working fine.

Comment: @CaptainQuint What are the values of rowId that you get? because the checkbox values are: value="' . $row['id'] . '", whereas the actual id's are: id="row'. $row['id'] .', so sensing might need document.getElementById('row' + rowId).style.color = "#4D4A49";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used:

```
'<tr id="row'. $row['id'] .'">'
```

but

```
var rowId = check_array[i].value;
document.getElementById(rowId).style.color = "#4D4A49";
```

is using the value attribute from the checkboxes which are set to:

```
value="' . $row['id'] . '"
```

hence either change:

```
document.getElementById('row' + rowId).style.color = "#4D4A49";
```

or

```
'<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox'. $row['id'] .'"  value="row' . $row['id'] . '" onchange="disableUser(this.value)" ' . ($row['disable'] == 0 ? 'checked' : '') .'/>'
```

Comment: That did it. I can't believe I forgot to add the "row" part to the id. So what I did was:
`var rowId = "row" + check_array[i].value;`

Thanks for the help. It's much appreciated.